# Django: Add model object to aggregated queryset

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, orm

Is there a way to add object to aggregated queryset?
For example:

```
qs = Model.objects.filter(title="abc").aggregate(likes=Count('likes'))
```

and i want to do something like:

```
qs = Model.objects.filter(title="abc").aggregate(likes=Count('likes')).get(pk=1)
```

Comment: You want annotate, not (or as well as)  aggregate, so you can refer to object.likes_count or whatever name you give the annotation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever a queryset is evaluated, its results are cached. However, this cache does not carry over if you use another method, such as `filter` or `order_by` or `get`, on the queryset. SO you can't try to evaluate the bigger set, and use filtering on the queryset to retrieve the smaller sets without doing another query.

So you can go by doing it this way:

```
qs = Model.objects.filter(pk=1, title="abc")
```

if the `qs` is `None` you do not have data that matches the query to start with, if it is not `None` you can go and do it like this:

```
qs_agg = qs.aggregate(likes=Count('likes'))
```

- `qs` here is the one that we got from the filtering